# SVN to GIT cloning issue

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I am pretty new to GIT and I'm trying to migrate our code from SVN to GIT.

The challenge I'm facing is, the GIT repos are already created and we are supposed to use them.

Here are the steps I followed.

1. `git clone ssh://git_url/project/service/repo.git` to clone the empty repo from stash into a folder called "new git repo"
2. `git svn clone --trunk=ABC/XYZ/development https://svnurl/svn/repository`

It is creating a folder structure like this
[image]

The command is created a subrepo inside the main repo.

Is there any way to achieve the following structure

[image]

After doing some research I tried the `git svn clone` command without doing the step 1. It created a local repo but I'm not sure how to link to the remote repo.

We are not using branching or trunks or tags in svn. All the production code and development code is basically in "development" folder. The client is just maintaining an excel document to keep track of SVN revisions which is deployed into production, which I'm trying to avoid in GIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to **use `git svn clone`  command to migrate your svn repo to git repo directly, and then push the migrated git repo to remote**. You can use below commands directly:

```
git svn clone --trunk=ABC/XYZ/development https://svnurl/svn/repository
cd development
git remote add origin ssh://git_url/project/service/repo.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: before cloning the SVN, do i have to clone the empty repo from stash??

Comment: No, it's not necessary. You just need to add remote (`git remote add`) for the migrated git repo.

Comment: `git svn clone` command worked but it did not recursively capture the svn commits of the files and folders.

Also it some how created remote branches like this

origin
     |_ trunk
subversion

Comment: The command will only get the related commits which you made changes for the development folder in svn repo. For the remote branch `remotes/git-svn` it only record the commit when you migate to git repo. If you don't need to get changes from svn to the migrated repo, you can also delete the file `.git/refs/remotes/git-svn` and the folder `.git/svn/` under the migrated git repo.

Comment: Have you solved the problem yet? If yes, you can mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.